# UITableView setting parentView property multiple times on rowselect

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

In a Single-View iOS app I'm currently working on, I have a view controller designed to manage playback of an audio stream, as well as a series of UI elements for playback control, scrolling, etc...For the sake of clarity, we'll call it `AudioStreamerViewController`.

A 'track selection' button in this view is wired to an action displays a `TrackSelectionTableViewController` modally, with the intention of allowing the user to select a track and return to the playback view when `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` gets called.
When this row selected method fires, the objective is to message the delegate callback method in `AudioStreamerViewController` that then attempts to execute `self.currentTrack = trackObjPassedToCallback`.

The problem is `AudioStreamerViewController` calls its `currentTrack` setter a seemingly infinite number of times (like an "I have to stop the simulator or I'll run out of memory" number of times), and I cannot seem to figure out why.  [I took a screenshot](http://www.screencast.com/t/IfGL1Av9S) of the call stack.  It had a breakpoint set so it only shows seven calls in the image, but believe me, it'll keep going =)

I'm wiring the two ViewControllers up by making `AudioStreamerViewController` the `TrackSelectionTableViewController`'s delegate using the following prototype:

```c
// in TrackSelectionTableViewController.h

@interface TrackSelectionTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *tracks;    
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<TrackSelectionTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@protocol 
// in TrackSelectionTableViewController.m
@synthesize delegate;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      Track *trackSelected = [tracks objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
      [self.delegate userDidSelectTrackFromTableView:trackSelected ];
      [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
```

`AudioStreamerViewController`'s prototype and delegate callback look like:

```
// in AudioStreamerViewController.h
@interface AudioStreamerViewController : UIViewController <SCDJTrackSelectionViewControllerDelegate> {
    Track *currentTrack;
}
@property (nonatomic) Track *currentTrack;

-(void)userDidSelectTrackFromTableView:(id)trackObj;

// in AudioStreamerViewController.m
@synthesize currentTrack;
-(void)userDidSelectTrackFromTableView:(id)trackObj
{
    self.currentTrack = (Track *)trackObj;
    // other handling code...
}
```

I've tried to do this a number of ways, and each of them produce the same end result.  Can anyone identify any indicators of why this is happening?  Also, is there a more attractive / stable approach to implementing this idea? If so, what are the benefits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your stack trace. `-setCurrentTrack:` is calling `-setCurrentTrack:`. What is your code for `-setCurrentTrack:`?

Comment: Yep. An old setter named -setCurrentTrack that existed before I added the currentTracks property was commented out in AudioStreamerViewController.h and not in the .m file.  Its implementation would override the synthesized setter for the currentTrack property and create a chain of calls to what would route back as itself. Careless refactoring leads to careless mistakes, and that code shouldn't have been there in the first place, let alone commented out =)